# Visual Studio 2022 (v 17.3.1) seems to be removing my SSL certificate

Tags: c#, iis, visual-studio-2022, .net-4.8

I run IIS locally for my work development, using Windows 10 Home edition. I have gone through the laborious procedure of making my own SSL certificate, self-signed, and adding it to my trusted certificate providers, because I absolutely must run SSL locally.

This works fine. Except that Visual Studio removes my SSL binding from the default website the first time I (edit) DEBUG (not run) my SSL application from within Visual studio. I have to re-bind the certificate every single time I load the project and debug it for the first time. This only happens on the first debug session. After that it no longer removes the certificate unless I shut down visual studio and reload it again. The very same website loads fine if I don't debug it in visual studio and just hit a page of the application.

The only reason I know it's Visual Studio doing this is because I can reproduce it this way, and I have tested it. The certificate stays bound just fine through a reboot, and is removed instantly the first time I run any of our servers locally that are SSL-only.

I don't think there is anything special about our projects except they are old .NET framework projects. This didn't always happen, I think it began about 6 months to a year ago.

I do see an event in event viewer telling me:

> SSL Certificate Settings deleted for endpoint : 0.0.0.0:443.

But that's all it tells me. I get no messages about this or anything, I just happen to know that Visual Studio removes my cert all the time so I go re-add it when the site doesn't work.

Any tips to try to diagnose this myself? Anybody else run into this issue and have a fix? Any and all advice is welcome.

This reproduces the issue 100% of the time for me:

- Install a self-signed certificate and add the provider to trusted.
  Bind the certificate to localhost.
- Verify the certificate works by loading something, anything over ssl
- Run a .NET framework 4.8 SSL website in Visual Studio 2022 V 17.3.1.
- Launch Profile Settings: Default settings (in-process hosting model, although I don't think it matters, I will check)

**Expected Result**: The SSL certificate works and is still bound to the default website

**Actual Result**: The SSL certificate is unbound, and needs to be re-bound manually

Comment: Your SSL is invalid or deleted because of that endpoint fails . I found that article about this particular issue https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-administration-management/https-connections-fail-ssl-bindings-deleted   Article directs you to delete the certificate then you can add a new one from scratch .

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/event-id-15300-ssl-certificate-settings-deleted/ba-p/1480925

Comment: No, that setting is not in my applicationhost file. And the bindings are very simple. My customMetadata tag is empty. This is literally the entire custommetadata section in my applicationhost config <customMetadata />. Also, the certificate is not removed randomly. It is removed the first time (and only the first time) I try to debug the site with Visual Studio 2022. After that it works fine with the same certificate, I just have to manually re-bind it.

Comment: Are you using Azure cloud services? If yes, you will need to have access to the Visual Studio solution to implement a valid certificate.

Comment: @YurongDai - no I am not using azure in the projects that cause the issue. And of course I have access to the solution - this is for my job so I am talking about running the solution from within Visual Studio. My SSL certificate runs fine as long as I do not debug it with Visual Studio. The first time I do that (and only the first time, per-load of Visual Studio) it removes my certficate. It doesn't happen again until I shut down visual studio, restart it, and run the site again. I suspect it's some kind of issue with the web debug properties, since they changed that UI for no apparent reason.

Comment: Sometimes Visual Studio may require administrator privileges to properly access and manage SSL certificates, please try running Visual Studio as an administrator and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: @YurongDai - thank you for the suggestion. I always run VS as administrator because it doesn't work with IIS otherwise. I'm about to try something that I hope will fix this, and if so I will post an answer myself.

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution to your problem? Any progress on this issue?

Comment: @YurongDai Nope, thanks for asking but I just deal with it by re-adding the certificate. Since it's not hard to fix I haven't dug into it much.

Comment: I haven't resolved it yet but I think I may have finally found the clue I needed - when I ping localhost from the commandline, it resolves to IPv6.  I figured this out because I had an unrelated problem. Thing is, IPv6 is disabled on all my active nics, so I'm not sure why it's doing that. But I bet if I can get that to stop happening, my launches will start working without destroying my bindings. Will update with answer if successful.